# Loose Coupling with ServiceProvider and DependencyInjection creates connection problems with SQL Database

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service-provider

I have two interfaces IDatabaseManager and ICRUDManager with the respective classes DatabaseManager and CRUDManager, configured in main class with configurationService, with DatabaseManager being singleton added with AddSingleton, and CRUDManager with AddTransient. The services are then accessed with service provider. I configure in main class the `DatabaseManger.SetConnection()` with the connection string and the `GetConnection` is accessed from CRUDManagerService. But the connection breaks when i access the GetConnection from one function to another.

```
public class Program
    {
        private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConfigureServices();
            var databaseService = serviceProvider.GetService<IDatabaseManager>();
            var crudService = serviceProvider.GetService<ICRUDManager>();

            databaseService.SetConnection(connectionString);
            crudService.Read();
            crudService.Update();
            crudService.Read();


        }
        private static void ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddTransient<ICRUDManager, CRUDManager>();
            services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseManager, DatabaseManager>(); 
            serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

```
public class DatabaseMananger: IDatabaseManager
{
    static SqlConnection connection;

    public SetConnection(connectionString)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
    public GetConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }

}
```

```
public class CRUDMananger: ICRUDManager
{
    IDatabaseManager databaseManager;

    public CRUDMananger(IDatabaseManager _databaseManager)
    {
        databaseManager = _databaseManager;
    }
    public string Read()
    {
        using(databaseManager.GetConnection()
        {
        //reads table
        }
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        using(databaseManager.GetConnection()
        {
        //updates table
        }
    }

}
```

All functions in CRUDManager runs good when unit testing,as the databaseManager is passed by tight coupling. But due to design fault, or some other problem I do not realize, after setting the connection, only the first read works in the main and the next update or read stops working due to empty conneciton string, or sql connection error. What I want to know is, if its the fault with the code architecture, whether its the fault of using singletons, or with dependencyInjection with ServiceProvider that connection resets and how can I make it better?

Comment: Since the database manager class is a singleton, potentially multiple threads attempt to use the same SqlConnection at the same time, which won't work.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem.

Comment: Databasemanager.connection does not need to be static since you are initializing as singleton. I would not create a method for SetConnection explicitly but instead set the connection fieldas 
```
private _connectionString;
private Lazy<SqlConnection> connection = new Lazy<SqlConnection>(() => new SqlConnection(_connectionString));
```
The connection string will need to be injected into the constructor of DatabaseManager as a separate dependency.